# Send message from drupal to WhatsApp

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I would like to send notifications from my webserver to my smartphone, preferably through one of the popular mobile chat apps like WhatsApp, Viber or Kik.

Is there any known documentation or API or something, that describes how to send a message to these clients, for example using PHP?

Note that I only need to be able to send notifications to my own smartphone, so requiring specific info to identify my particular client (like cellphone number or something) is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there have been some, but whatsapp changed their security system and shut off the api - so there is no known way anymore.

For Example:
https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI and
http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/07/send-whatsapp-messages-via-php-script-using-whatsapi/

Comment: For Example: https://github.com/venomous0x/WhatsAPI and http://blog.philippheckel.com/2013/07/07/send-whatsapp-messages-via-php-script-using-whatsapi/

Answer (score 0):

There is a module [Drupal WhatsApp](https://www.drupal.org/project/whatsapp)

**NOTICE: This module uses an unofficial API library for sending WhatsApp, which may mean that may stop working without notice.
USE THIS MODULE RESPONSIBLY AND WITHOUT USING SPAM BECAUSE THEY COULD BAN OF ITS SERVERS THE USED PHONE NUMBER.**